# create elasticsearch query with optional params

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I'm trying to create an elasticsearch query that have the following logic: search by title, and if the type of record is given, also add it to the query. I did this

```
  def to_es_query
    {
      query: {
        match: {
          title_en: { query: @title }
        }.merge!(optional_params)
      }
    }
  end

  def optional_params
    type_param
  end

  def type_param
    return {} unless @type
    {
      match: {
        type: {
          query: @type
        }
      }
    }
  end
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Is it the ruby part that's not working or you don't know how to write the ES query?

Comment: I don't know how to write the query in ruby

Comment: Ok then, can't help you.

Comment: well, maybe you can. I'm generating this query in ruby: `{:query=>{:match=>{:title_en=>{:query=>"star wars"}, :type=>{:query=>"serie"}}}}` but it is not working. Is this query right, based on what I want?

Comment: No, it doesn't look right. I think it should be like this: `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title_en": "star wars"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "type": "serie"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE** (previous answer removed because it was wrong)

After reading a bit about elastic search I think this will work for you

```
def to_es_query
  { query:  { bool: { must: musts } } } 
end
def musts
  @musts ||= [{ match:{ title_en: @title  } }]
  #possibly { term: {type: @type } } } would work for an exact search 
  # e.g. type = 'serie'
  @musts << { match: { type:  @type } } if @type 
  @musts 
end
```

This will create a boolean search where all the criteria must be true

Taken from [Combining Filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html)

Comment: Changed, my query looks like this `=> {:query=>{:match=>{:title_en=>{:query=>"star wars"}, :type=>{:query=>"serie"}}}}` but still, getting error 400 from ES. but if the query is right, the problem is not with the query hahahaha

Comment: @LuizE. Okay i think I understand elastic search a bit better now after reading a little. See if my update works for you. You actually need to combine the filters using a `bool` query. Also checkout the link it was very helpful

Comment: this is a cleaner answer, and more in line with the original question